# Running Squid on localhost

Tags: proxy, squid

I have a product form Symantec and their help is...less than helpful, including a nice message that says "Contact your reseller" in the "Contact Us" link.  My reseller says to contact them.  How?  Anyways, it's a repackaged version if Squid for Windows.  When I point IE to the proxy running locally I get "Access Denied.  Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect."  However, when I point IE on another machine to the server running Squid everything works fine.

I have zero experience with Squid or proxies. I tried some different configs based on searches here but nothing worked.  I'm sure it's something simple.  Here is the config:

```
digest_generation off

hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?

acl all src 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0

cache deny all

maximum_object_size 0 KB

emulate_httpd_log on

debug_options ALL,1

cache_store_log none
access_log none
useragent_log none

auth_param ntlm program c:/clientsiteproxy/libexec/mswin_ntlm_auth.exe
auth_param ntlm children 80
auth_param ntlm keep_alive on

auth_param negotiate children 80

auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Squid proxy-caching web server
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
auth_param basic casesensitive off

authenticate_ip_shortcircuit_ttl 30 seconds

refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320

read_timeout 15 minutes

acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8
acl SSL_ports port 443 563
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443 563 # https, snews
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl Smartconnect dstdomain ned.webscanningservice.com
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl authproxy proxy_auth REQUIRED

acl our_networks src 192.168.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/12 10.0.0.0/8 169.254.0.0/16
acl HEAD method HEAD

http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

http_access allow HEAD
http_access deny !our_networks
http_access allow Smartconnect

http_access allow authproxy
http_access deny all

icp_access allow all

httpd_suppress_version_string on

visible_hostname ClientSiteProxy

forwarded_for off

header_access Via deny all

never_direct allow all

cache_dir null c:/ClientSiteProxy
coredump_dir c:/clientsiteproxy/var/cache

http_port 3128
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely the culprit: `http_access deny !our_networks`. This statement denies outbound access for all source IPs apart from `192.168.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/12 10.0.0.0/8 169.254.0.0/16`.

When you browse from the same machine, browser would bind on localhost, so you can try expanding the `our_networks` definition with `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I added 127.0.0.1 and now I get:  

Unable to forward this request at this time.  

This request could not be forwarded to the origin server or to any parent caches. The most likely cause for this error is that: 
•The cache administrator does not allow this cache to make direct connections to origin servers, and 
•All configured parent caches are currently unreachable.

Comment: Try removing `never_direct allow all`. Are you sure this works for non-localhost clients?